# Was Anne McCaffrey the first person to have different types of dragons be different colours?

Tags: history-of, dragons, pern

It has become something of a trope to have different types of dragons be different colours. You have Gold, Bronze, Brown, Green and Blue on Anne McCaffrey's Pern, and at least ten different species in Dungeons and Dragons.  In modern fiction, was McCaffrey the first person to depict different types of dragon, either separate species or as on Pern, "castes" within a species, differentiated by colour?  I'm not interested in simple colour variations, such as Tolkien's Smaug the Red and Ancalagon the Black, where there is no other difference.

Comment: I won't do the full research, but no. They're even different colors in medieval heraldry.  Don't worry, though; there's good people working on great answers for this. Have an updoot!

Comment: Medieval is the optative word. This question spans over a thousand years and multiple languages. This is not answerable.

Comment: Predated at least by Tolkein (Smaug (red), Ancalagon the Black) and even earlier by Chinese mythology (e.g. the Dragon Kings - Azure Dragon, White Dragon etc.)

Comment: Seems perfectly answerable to me, albeit a bit trivial of a question.  It's not asking for the first, it's asking if Anne McCaffery was the first.  All you have to do is find an example that predates it and you've answered the question.

Comment: Edited to clarify my question.  I'm asking about distinct types of dragon, not just colour variations such as Tolkien's

Comment: Right, so this would be the difference between "a dragon that is red" and a "Red Dragon", right?

Answer (score 3):

The question is flawed as written I think, however short answer as mentioned in the comments, no, dragons have been depicted as various colors since most likely the first time someone thought of dragons.  As a comment mentioned look at medieval heraldry for evidence of this.  Western and eastern dragons could also be an example depending on how you would classify sub-species.

However I must point out that the dragons of Pern are not really different types except as far as phenotype and perhaps slight differences in psychology,  while in D&D different color dragons actually have different abilities, so the question I think you wanted to ask was, was Gary Gygax the first person to conceive of different types of dragons being able to do different things.

EDIT:  L.  Frank Baum included dragons of a different color in his Oz books including a purple dragon (which is the most terrifying type of dragon to fight) along with blind dragons and draggonettes which could be considerd sub-species I suppose.

Comment: They're asking about modern fictions, making your answer and comment, unnecessary and rude.

Comment: Hmmm did not see the edit before I posted

Comment: I have no idea what the cutoff date for "modern fiction" is, but since fiction has been around for most of recorded human history, I consider Baum to be fairly modern, as compared to say, the Epic of Gilgamesh, the Illiad, or even Don Quixote. However, even if Baum isn't "modern", I didn't find Revenant's answer to be unnecessary or rude.